# How to remove Home- from the site title?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I added the title from the customize option field

[image]

I am getting

[image]

Even in the admin panel at the top, I am getting correct.

[image]

But When I check my home page on the browser then I am getting the Home - This is blog website

[image]

I want to know how to remove the Home - from the title.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Yoast SEO or anything like that? if that's not the case then you should check your theme inside header.php file and see what get's printed in the title tag of your HTML.

If you want further help you should paste code or give us some more info

Comment: Yes, I am using the Yoast SEO plugin. I notice that the page title is showing in the site title. For example, site-title-This is blog website

Comment: Then you should check your Yoast settings here: wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_titles and remove the parts you don't want

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have two possibilities. You can setup this configuration for all the pages or each page individually.

For all the pages simply go to SEO > Search Appearance then select Content Types. There, you will find the default configuration for each content type and one of the pages will look like this:
[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Xxd.png)

You simply need to remove the separator and site title.

If you want to change this for each page individually you need to edit the page. Locate the Yoast block, click on the title then edit it:
[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02wwE.png)